# Azure blob storage images cause security issues when sharing webpages in Facebook

Tags: facebook, azure, security, azure-blob-storage

All website images are stored in the Azure blob storage with standard urls like:

> https://****.blob.core.windows.net/*.jpg

Each page has "og:image" with link to the image stored in the blob.

When I am trying to share some web page I see a security issue (or similar messages with asking to enter captcha because of unsecured content):

[image]

I can't find any official references by Microsoft or Facebook how to fix this issue or whitelist the domain.

Comment: The URL in the screenshot is using `http`. does changing it to `https` make is "safe"?

Comment: No, 'https' is not a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I get same security issue warning when I try to post your image on Facebook. If you ensure the included images are safe and Facebook made mistake, you could click ***[let us know]*** to report it.

```
<meta property="og:image"              content="https://donorua.blob.core.windows.net/public-images/df1f3ede-6502-46fc-8c52-10317d8e5a6e.jpg" />
```

[image]

Besides, I save your image in my Blob container, and then post the image, I find the imgae could be posted. So if possible, please try to move the images to another container or rename the images in your Azure Blob container.

[image]

Comment: Temporary moved images to the other subdomain. And kindly ask to edit the image and remove a man from it. Thanks!